# Windows 10 IoT Core Bluetooth Support for Raspberry Pi3

Tags: bluetooth, driver, iot, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

Apologies for asking a time dependant question, but does anyone know when Microsoft are going to sort out there drivers for the Raspberry Pi 3's on-board Bluetooth chip?

Currently the console Device Settings just display the following exception error code relating to a fault with the OS files:

> The device is not ready for use. (Excep_FromHResult 0x800710DF)

[image]

**Or** does anyone know of a workaround to this problem?... Short of developing your own drivers and creating a custom OS image for the board.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 3 onboard Bluetooth support is in a future release of Windows IoT Core Insider Preview, per the [page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/whatsnew) it should come soon, so please be patient.

The workaround is to use a compatible USB Bluetooth dongle, check out [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/supportedinterfaces#Bluetooth-Dongles) to find the list.

If you want to develop your own driver and create a custom image for hobby or fun, you can find very good code samples in https://github.com/ms-iot/bsp/tree/master/drivers, and follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/iot/iot-core-manufacturing-guide
 to create custom windows IoT core image.

Update!!!

Onboard Bluetooth driver seems to be included in the latest preview build version 14376. I did not test it thoroughly but per the snapshots below, it looks very promising.
[image]
[image]